# django-tables2 How to set Verbose name for _set

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-tables2

I have a value `ccu_set.all.first.player_count`.

Which works perfectly, but I want to change the verbose name so that in the table it doesn't say "ccu_set.all.first.player_count".

However when I do:

```
ccu_set.all.first.player_count = tables.Column(verbose_name= 'CCU', default='')
```

It gives the following error:

> NameError: name 'ccu_set' is not defined

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it by adding a @property to the model

```
@property
    def latest_ccu(self):
        try:
            return self.ccu_set.first().player_count
        except:
            return None
```

Then I just did

```
latest_ccu = tables.Column(verbose_name= 'CCU', default='')
```